# Differentiate between mentioned post and post on wall

Tags: api, facebook-fql

When you query the stream table for a fan page wall contents, you get back contents posted on the fanpage wall mentioning the page and also posts from a fan on their own wall which mention the page. Is there a way to distinguish between these two types in the stream response?

For example, here is a fan page http://www.facebook.com/signalhq which pulls a post from a user who has tagged the page in his own post

http://www.facebook.com/jeff.judge/posts/10150356144351153

Is there a way to differentiate this above post from other posts on that wall? I can't find anything in the fql stream api doc to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a slight modification of ifaour's post, you should run this FQL query:

SELECT target_id, post_id, message, actor_id, tagged_ids FROM stream WHERE source_id = PAGEID

The target_id field will allow you to know the object that the Post was made on. If this was the user posting on their own wall (and tagging the Page) then the target_id won't be the Page's ID. If the user posted on the Page wall AND tagged the Page in that post, then the target_id will be the Page ID.

Check out target_id on the stream FQL docs to make this clear: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Edit: Clarification of the results you should be seeing:

A Post by the Page on the Pages Wall:

- target_id = null
- actor_id = PAGEID

A Post by a user on the Pages Wall:

- target_id = PAGEID
- actor_id = USERID

A Post by a user on their own wall that tags the Page:

- target_id = null
- actor_id = USERID

Hopefully this should help you to differentiate?

Comment: This is not true, tried it and it's returning null for target_id

Comment: Same here, null for target_id

Comment: Null in which particular case? I think it should be null if a user or Page is making the post on their own wall. If otherwise, I should look into this as a bug

Comment: It is null for all the posts returned including the one I am interested in : http://www.facebook.com/jeff.judge/posts/10150356144351153

Comment: Okay, I've put some clarification in my original post - if this isn't the behaviour that you're seeing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you pull this post in JSON format from the Graph-API, There are "from" and "to" JSON objects in it as well...

They should be able to help you in distinguishing between the two posts

HIH!

Comment: True but tagged_ids already give me that information, I need a way to distinguish between posts on users' wall and fan page wall both of which mention the page.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be retrieving the `tagged_ids` field:

```
SELECT post_id, message, actor_id, tagged_ids FROM stream WHERE source_id = 'PAGE_ID'
```

This would return something like:

```
[
  {
    "post_id": "PAGE_ID_255888737767539",
    "message": "PAGE_NAME test",
    "actor_id": MY_ID,
    "tagged_ids": [
      PAGE_ID
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_id": "PAGE_ID_156571787756776",
    "message": "",
    "actor_id": PAGE_ID,
    "tagged_ids": []
  }
]
```

If the page ID presents in the `tagged_ids` field and the `actor_id` is NOT the page id then the page is mentioned by a user.

Comment: Agreed, that solves only half my problem. I need to differentiate between posts on the fan page which mention the page vs posts on user's wall which mention the page. Both posts show up in stream and there is no way to distinguish between the two.

Comment: It seems that Facebook is giving the ownership of the post to the page! if you check the `post_id` it starts with the page_id even if it was posted on the user's wall!