# Distinguishing between a Facebook post on a page's wall, and a post which mentions the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find anything in the Facebook Graph API that will allow me to distinguish between a post which @mentions a page (whether that post be by a user or a page) and a post which is posted on the page's wall (which could also include an @mention of the page).

For example, both types of post will have 'to' and 'from' fields, both might have a 'messaege_tags' field, both may have the same 'type' and both will appear in the feed of the page in question but not in '/posts' for the page in question.

I have looked at [Differentiate between mentioned post and post on wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181287/differentiate-between-mentioned-post-and-post-on-wall), but this talks about FQL queries which is now deprecated.

Does anyone know of anyway to distinguish between the two types?

Comment: Why would the post made _by_ the page not appear in `/posts`? That is the very definition of that edge, according to docs: _“`/{page-id}/posts` shows only the posts that were published by this page”_

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the posts made by a page, use the following edge:

```
/{page-id}/posts
```

To fetch @mentions and posts by other users to the page, use:

```
/{page-id}/tagged
```

For the specific use case that you mentioned above, you should be using a page access token with both calls.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question